# Missing RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-x86_64 during system upgrade

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

While trying to run `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=32` I got the following error right after all the packages have downloaded and are about to install:

```
warning: /var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/kernel-core-5.6.10-300.fc32.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 12c944d0: NOKEY
Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-x86_64 [Couldn't open file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-x86_64]
```

The message is not wrong. There is no file there with that name. What tool is meant to download and install GPG keys for me and how do I run it? I'm guessing this isn't something I should have to do manually.

---

Before this I also saw an error similar to the following:

```
warning: kernel-core.fc25.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID abcdef12
```

This lead me to https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Installing_and_Upgrading.html

> If you do not have the appropriate key installed to verify the signature, the message contains the word NOKEY:

Great, the page has info about installing keys but nothing about where to actually download them .

Answer (score 6):

I ended up doing this manually. It needed 3 keys and a symlink:

1. The main fedora key:

   ```
   sudo su
   cd /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/
   wget https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/fedora-repos/raw/master/f/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-primary
   ln -s RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-primary RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-32-x86_64
   ```
2. Rpmfusion free and nonfree keys:

   `links https://rpmfusion.org/keys # terminal based browser :)`

   (Skip the bit with "gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys Key_ID" - it didn't do anything for me)

   Download "RPM Fusion free for Fedora 32" and "RPM Fusion nonfree for Fedora 32".

   Save them to, or save and move to, `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/`.

   This unblocked the system upgrade for me. However I did notice existing keys would be saved as `*-primary` and have a symlink to that instead.

Comment: Had to change `master` to `rawhide`.